# How to attach to User create multiple checkboxes during laravel authentication

Tags: database, laravel, authentication, relational-database

Good afternoon everyone!

In my project I have to create a new user which will be a restaurant directly in the user's registration.

Once registered, I gave the possibility to associate more types of restaurant to the logged in user.

I made already migrations and relations everything is working.
This is what i wrote to permit the logged user(restaurant) to add more typologies.

```
public function typologyAdd() {
  $typologies = Typology::all();
  return view('pages.typology-add',compact('typologies'));
}
public function typologyStore(Request $request) {
 $data = $request -> all();
 $user = Auth::user();
 $typologies = Typology::findOrFail($data['typologies']);
 $user -> typologies() -> sync($typologies);
 return redirect() -> route('home');
}
```

So this is working only once i register the user.
i want to put this logic when i'm in registration page.

I was trying to modify the RegisterController but i don't know how to do that:

```
protected function validator(array $data)
{
    return Validator::make($data, [
        'name' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
        'email' => ['required', 'string', 'email', 'max:255', 'unique:users'],
        'indirizzo' => ['required' ,'string','max:255'],
        'piva' => ['required','string','min:11','max:11','digits:11','unique:users'],
        'password' => ['required', 'string', 'min:8', 'confirmed'],
    ]);
}

/**
 * Create a new user instance after a valid registration.
 *
 * @param  array  $data
 * @return \App\User
 */
protected function create(array $data)
{
    return User::create([
        'name' => $data['name'],
        'email' => $data['email'],
        'indirizzo' => $data['indirizzo'],
        'piva' => $data['piva'],
        'password' => Hash::make($data['password']),
    ]);
}
```

and to put checkboxes inside the Register.blade.php

```
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <div class="card">

                @if ($errors->any())
                  <div class="alert alert-danger">
                     <ul>
                         @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
                             <li>{{ $error }}</li>
                         @endforeach
                     </ul>
                  </div>
                @endif

                <div class="card-header">{{ __('Register') }}</div>

                <div class="card-body">
                    <form method="POST" action="{{ route('register') }}">
                        @csrf

                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="name" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('Name') }}</label>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input id="name" type="text" class="form-control @error('name') is-invalid @enderror" name="name" value="{{ old('name') }}" required autocomplete="name" autofocus>

                                @error('name')
                                    <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                        <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @enderror
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="email" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('E-Mail Address') }}</label>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input id="email" type="email" class="form-control @error('email') is-invalid @enderror" name="email" value="{{ old('email') }}" required autocomplete="email">

                                @error('email')
                                    <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                        <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @enderror
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="password" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('Password') }}</label>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input id="password" type="password" class="form-control @error('password') is-invalid @enderror" name="password" required autocomplete="new-password">

                                @error('password')
                                    <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                        <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @enderror
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="password-confirm" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('Confirm Password') }}</label>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input id="password-confirm" type="password" class="form-control" name="password_confirmation" required autocomplete="new-password">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="indirizzo" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('indirizzo') }}</label>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                              <input id="indirizzo" type="text" class="form-control" name="indirizzo" value="{{ old('indirizzo') }}" maxlength="255" required>

                              @error('indirizzo')
                                  <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                      <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                                  </span>
                              @enderror
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="piva" minlenght="11" maxlength="11" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('piva') }}</label>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                              <input id="piva" type="text" class="form-control @error('piva') is-invalid @enderror" name="piva" value="{{ old('piva') }}" required>

                                @error('piva')
                                    <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                        <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @enderror
                            </div>

                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group row mb-0">
                            <div class="col-md-6 offset-md-4">
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
                                    {{ __('Register') }}
                                </button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I hope someone will give me some ideas on how to do it, thanks to those who will read and answer

Answer (score 0):

In the `RegisterController.php` you can get the newly created user by doing the below.

```
protected function create(array $data)
{
    $user = User::create([
        'name' => $data['name'],
        'email' => $data['email'],
        'indirizzo' => $data['indirizzo'],
        'piva' => $data['piva'],
        'password' => Hash::make($data['password']),
    ]);

    // Do actions on $user and finally return $user
 
    return $user;
}
```

Add new validations rules if you need any & also if you are doing relation data entry i would suggest to do a SQL transaction based insert. Commit data if no SQL error is thrown. Else rollback the changes to prevent issues.

Comment: thanks for the answer!! i was thinking to do that, but i need to show all my typologies from table typologies already in the registration page and of course when i try to "foreach them" in the register blade it does not recognize the variable $typologies. i'm trying to understand why.

Comment: Make sure that you are passing your variables to the view. View not recognising variables means the variables are not passed into the view in the first place. You may need to override the controller function that is responsible for generating the registration form for that. Once thats done you will be able to access the new input variable be it checkbox or radio buttons or something else. Do needed validation & do above $user object to do relation data entry.